# gdb "Attempt to take address of value not located in memory." when calling functions, even const

Tags: c++, gdb

I get errors even though there is no modification on the objects, very simple expression, calling a method:

```
(gdb) p my_unordered_map.count(edge.target_node_id)
$6 = 1

(gdb) p my_unordered_map[edge.target_node_id]
Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.
```

also I have the same error while calling a const function:

```
class A {
   Sub s;
   X get_x () const {
       return s.x;
   } 
};

(gdb) p a.get_x()
Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.

(gdb) p a.s.x
--works
```

I don't understand. So far, when evaluating an expression, I can rely on it not working.

The code is in a lambda. `A` is an argument, `my_unordered_map` is captured by reference.

(gdb 8.3)

Comment: and lldb 7.0.1 crashes in that lambda while getting watches

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would help you get a better answer. Please include build commands and the version of compiler used.